# Perl log message is unexpected written into dest file

Tags: perl, file-io

Here is a segment of test code for writing data to files,

```
open(OUT_FILE, ">", $destfile)||die("can not open file!");
select(OUT_FILE);
binmode(OUT_FILE);
printf "test file name:\t'%s'\n", $destfile;
writebinary(OUT_FILE,pack('H*', $name))
```

Log message "test file name: datatest.txt" is appended in datatest.txt
What's wrong?

Comment: What do you think [`select(OUT_FILE)`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) does?

Comment: Got it. thanks @Robby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html)ed your file handle `OUT_FILE`. `select` will make output from `print` and `printf` go to the selected handle instead of `STDOUT`, which is selected by default.

Remove the call to `select`. You don't need it.

---

Please note your code is very old-fashioned. It could be rewritten as follows, to take into account lexical file handles and proper error handling:

```
open my $fh, '>', $destfile or die "Can't open file '$destfile': $!";
binmode $fh;
printf "test file name:\t'%s'\n", $destfile;
writebinary($fh, pack('H*', $name));
```

Of course you're not telling us what `writebinary` does. You might need to make changes there. But keep in mind that glob filehandles are global, and other parts of your program might mess with your `OUT_FILE`.